# Subtract Next to the current and make that output as the data of that current row

Tags: mysql, sql

Computing Kilometer Run is based on this

`current value = next value - current value`

I have a table that looks like this.

[image]

My question is how can I compute the `kmr` based on the odometer value? I will replace the value of kmr column of kmr value

Comment: Imagine if you weren't you. Would this make any sense to you? Well, that's how we feel.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Can you please elaborate more what your try to say thanks

Comment: The linked answer says it all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work using rank and for MORE THAN one person

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c054e/1

```
Select m.`code`,m.vdate, ( n.kmr - m.kmr) as new_kmr
From
(Select t1.*, @rnk := @rnk + 1 as rnk
From tbl t1, (select @rnk := 0) t
Order by t1.`code`,t1.vdate) m left join
(Select t2.*, @rnk1 := @rnk1 + 1 as rnk
From tbl t2, (select @rnk1:= 0) t
Order by t2.`code`,t2.vdate) n
On m.`code` = n.`code`
And m.rnk + 1 = n.rnk 
Order by m.`code`, m.vdate
```

**Output:**

```
code            vdate          new_kmr
person 1    2018-03-01  10
person 1    2018-03-02  10
person 1    2018-03-03  (null)
person 2    2018-03-01  5
person 2    2018-03-02  (null)
```

Comment: plus 1 for effort :)

Comment: If you like my effort pls upvote my answer. Mabuhay! U can also email me at jbacoy3ATyahooDOTcom

Comment: looks like there are some changes and i change my accepted answer looks like yours fits my need. sorry i didnt gave this a chance to try and i just focused on the 1st answer. daghang slamat kaibgan haha

Comment: salamat kaayo. Maayong Pagkabanhaw sa Dios! gamay lang alam ko at di makasabot. haha

Comment: boss may question lng ako

Answer (score 3):

You can use variables to store last values.

> ```
> create table tbl (code varchar(10), vdate date, kmr int);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into tbl values
> ('Person1', '20180101', 71883),
> ('Person1', '20180102', 71893),
> ('Person1', '20180103', 71903),
> ('Person2', '20180101', 71800),
> ('Person2', '20180102', 71815),
> ('Person2', '20180103', 71820);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select code, vdate, kmr, current_kmr
> from
> (
>   select t1.code, t1.vdate, t1.kmr, 
>          t1.kmr - if(coalesce(@last_code, t1.code) = t1.code, coalesce(@last_kmr, t1.kmr), t1.kmr)  as current_kmr,
>          @last_kmr := t1.kmr,
>          @last_code := t1.code
>   from   tbl t1,
>          (select @last_kmr := null, @last_code := null) t2
>   order by t1.code, t1.vdate
> ) t
> ```
>
> ```
> code    | vdate      |   kmr | current_kmr
> :------ | :--------- | ----: | ----------:
> Person1 | 2018-01-01 | 71883 |           0
> Person1 | 2018-01-02 | 71893 |          10
> Person1 | 2018-01-03 | 71903 |          10
> Person2 | 2018-01-01 | 71800 |           0
> Person2 | 2018-01-02 | 71815 |          15
> Person2 | 2018-01-03 | 71820 |           5
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=ebb99bef991b7677524466002a65dc86)*

Comment: If there is another person, how would you fix it? It is breaking when there is person 2.

Comment: Awesome! You nailed it.

Comment: Im wondering based n your answer the row 1 must be 10 because it is row2 - row1 why your is 0?

Comment: He will fix it. No worries.

Comment: @anonyXmous we hope so

Comment: @McNets Good Morning. Im getting the wrong value based on your query